Unexpected output when using Jupyter
After printing the array in a for loop I also get an additional array of None for seemingly no reason
When running from file:
A= [1,2,3,4,5]
[print(i) for i in A]

prints
1
2
3
4
5

as expected.
However with Jupyter I also get an array on None of equal length to the original array:
#%%
A= [1,2,3,4,5]
[print(i) for i in A]

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]

The array disappears if I print something after printing the array, for example:
#%%
A= [1,2,3,4,5]
[print(i) for i in A]
print("test")

returns
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
test

Why does this happen?
I'm using Visual Studio Code (VSC), Python 3.11.19 and the Jupyter extension pack by Microsoft

You are not considering the big difference between a Python script and running in a  Jupyter notebook cell. The Jupyter notebook cell is under the REPL model where by default what the last expression returns is also displayed. Because each time that last expression returns from the list comprehension is 'None' because there's nothing returned, it has built up an array that it prints at the end. In this case, the easiest way to suppress that 'extra' is to change the last line to [print(i) for i in A];. Because of the addition of the semi-colon, the last expression returns nothing & so ...

 nothing extra gets shown in the output. The semi-colon isn't magical  or any special signal in Jupyter as some answers you may find on SO seem to think because some answers will often invoke it as a blanket way to suppress output from a cell. It just makes the code after it , which is no code, the last expression and so nothing is returned and nothing is put in the output from that line. It often comes in handy with code relating to plots because it will otherwise show the Python object code. Less so these days in modern Jupyter, but you'll encounter it from time to time.

print() returns None and Jupyter displays the List as the last expression in the Cell.

print(i) does the print and has a None value.  That's why the list comprehension is a list of None.  Run as a script the list is not displayed. Run interactively, the last line of the code block is displayed.

there are two things that you should note here:
[1] as per @Wayne (and others) comment. The last line in a Jupyter cell is always "displayed". In this case the print() statement returned None into the list at each iteration. So the last line was a list of None.
[2] unless you are intending to use the list later on in the code (i.e. assigning it to a variable), then it would be correct to write the same statement like this:

A= [1,2,3,4,5]
for i in A: print(i)


And, finally,  you could put an additional empty statement at the end.  Such as ; or print() or pass.

so it's because the brackets create another array with values returned by print that Jupyter prints at the end right?

@Krzyp,  yes, that is pretty much spot on.

I should also add that it is a very convenient feature for a notebook cell to print the last line.

@Wayne,  that is probably a better description.  i changed "printed" to "displayed" in the  text.  Thank you.
